# C++, How to call a function without passing full arguments

Tags: c++, arguments

I am looking into the source code of [qpOASES](https://github.com/jmirabel/qpOASES) project.

What made me confused, is how to call a function [here](https://github.com/jmirabel/qpOASES/blob/master/examples/example1.cpp#L69):

```
...
int nWSR = 10;
example.init( H,g,A,lb,ub,lbA,ubA, nWSR );
```

while the [target](https://github.com/jmirabel/qpOASES/blob/master/src/QProblem.cpp#L302) has different number of arguments:

```
returnValue QProblem::init( const real_t* const _H, const real_t* const _g, const real_t* const _A,
                            const real_t* const _lb, const real_t* const _ub,
                            const real_t* const _lbA, const real_t* const _ubA,
                            int_t& nWSR, real_t* const cputime,
                            const real_t* const xOpt, const real_t* const yOpt,
                            const Bounds* const guessedBounds, const Constraints* const guessedConstraints,
                            const real_t* const _R
                            )
{
    int_t i;
    int_t nV = getNV( );
    int_t nC = getNC( );
```

Not all arguments are passed but it functions properly and the rest of arguments are passed as `nullptr`:

---

[image]

---

I tried sending arguments to a function incompletely but it does not work for me. So why does it work for `qpOASES`?

```
void init(  int a, double* const cputime,
                            const double* const xOpt, const double* const yOpt,
                            const double* const _R
                            )
{
}


int main()
{
    init(0);

    return 0;
}
// test.cpp:12:8: error: too few arguments to function ‘void init(int, double*, const double*, const double*, const double*)’
//   init(0);
//         ^
// test.cpp:2:6: note: declared here
//  void init( int a, double* const cputime,
//       ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to call a function without passing full arguments

You'll have to provide values for all the arguments except for the ones that have a default value.

```
void foo(int a, int b, int c = 10) { ... }


foo(10, 20);    // Ok. c gets the default value of 10
foo(10, 20, 30);   // c gets the value of 30

foo(10);        // Not Ok. Value provided for a but not b
```

Comment: You are right. I only checked the implementation. I did not check the header file for declaration.